# Automatically increase width of plot with the number of subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-visualization

I would like to know how I can generate a graph that increases in width with the number of subplots.

I am trying to create a graph which contains multiple boxplots:

```py
def create_box_plot(vals_dict, max_val):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    
    # set axes limits and labels
    plt.ylim(0, max_val)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    
    counter, positionss = 1, []
    # first boxplot pair
    for vals in vals_dict.values():
        positions = [i for i in range(counter, counter + len(vals))]
        positionss.append(positions)
        bp = plt.boxplot(vals, positions=positions, widths=0.6, showfliers=False)
        
        counter += len(vals) + 1
    
    ax.set_xticklabels(list(vals_dict.keys()))
    ax.set_xticks([np.mean(positions) for positions in positionss])
    
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    
    plt.savefig(buf, aspect='auto', dpi=300, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    plt.close()
```

If I e.g. set the `figzise` to `(20, 1)`, then for a large number of subplots I get a good enough looking graph:
[image]

but if I only have a few boxplots or if the labels are long the graph looks awful:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you mean subplots, you mean boxes in your plot, right?

Pass a `figsize` argument to `plt.figure` and make the figsize values a value dependant on the number of boxes you are going to plot.